# getting updated distribute via pip requirements file

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-10.04, pip, django-rest-framework

im using pip requirements file for the dependencies with virtualenv. im using ubuntu10.04LTS now the problem has come up with djangorestframework, after adding it in .pip file

while downloading the requirements @URLObject  error occurs and says

> Downloading/unpacking URLObject>=0.6.0 (from djangorestframework->-r /var/lib/myproj/base.pip (line 26))
>     Using download cache from /usr/local/pipcache/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2FU%2FURLObject%2FURLObject-2.0.1.tar.gz
>     Running setup.py egg_info for package URLObject
>       The required version of distribute (>=0.6.24) is not available,
>       and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
>       install a more recent version first, using
>       'easy_install -U distribute'.
>       (Currently using distribute 0.6.10 (/var/lib/myproj/.ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.6.egg))
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       The required version of distribute (>=0.6.24) is not available,
>   and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
>   install a more recent version first, using
>   'easy_install -U distribute'
>   (Currently using distribute 0.6.10 (/var/lib/myproj/.ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.6.egg))

my pip requirement file is as follows:

```
virtualenv
django
distribute
django-permissions
django-storages
django-sentry
#django-db-utils
PIL
#Required for APIs
djangorestframework
```

i have even tried by adding distribute-0.6.25 but in vain how do i upgrade distribute via pip requirements file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just hit the same issue.

Solved by running:

```
pip install -U distribute==0.6.25
```

I don't think you can update it via the requirements file because requirements are installed at once and not one by one.

Comment: --thanks for the quick reply, im getting this error ** ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'pip install -U distribute==0.6.25', 'at', ' intall -U distribute==0.6.25')**  on adding the above line in pip file

Comment: Run the command "pip install -U distribute==0.6.25" in the shell. Don't put it in requirements !

Comment: i dont have permissions to do in shell. is there any way out by keeping in requirements file. more over i have python2.6.5 version in ubuntu10.04lts

Comment: Did you try: 0. backup and empty requirements 1. add **only** distribute==0.6.25 in requirements 2. upload requirements for update and 3. restore the requirements backup ?

Answer (score 0):

if you need distribute to be 0.6.25 version, just specify it in the requirements:

```
virtualenv
django
distribute==0.6.25
django-permissions
django-storages
django-sentry
#django-db-utils
PIL
#Required for APIs
djangorestframework
```